# How to pass compiler option to R source package install

Tags: r, icc

Installing `sp` package on Linux from source.
To use Intel compiler I need to pass `-std=c99` to compiler otherwise `=for(int j...`= gives errors.
But `install.packages("sp", configure.vars = data.frame(CFLAGS = "-std=c99"))` ignores my added argument. The R documentation is vague on this.

Comment: One way is to create a `.R/makevars` file, and write `CC = gcc -std=c99` inside.

Comment: Below article on Intel Developer Zone describes the procedure to build R package with Intel Compiler and Intel MKL library: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/build-r-301-with-intel-c-compiler-and-intel-mkl-on-linux. Hope this helps.

Comment: Modifying .R/Makevars (note the capital M) solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AnoopMadhusoodhananPrabha I didn't find information about R packages on that page, just the base R in compile/install.